# Subtyping relationship in a simple type system

Tags: type-theory

This example is from [Algebraic Subtyping, p. 14](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sd601/thesis.pdf). Let's say we have a type system with just function types, $\bot$ and $\top$; propositions involving type variables are defined by quantification over ground types.

I understand why $$(\bot \rightarrow \top) \rightarrow \bot \leqslant (\alpha \rightarrow \bot) \sqcup \alpha$$ holds. But how do I convince myself that it no longer holds when the type system is extended with a more general function type $\tau_1 \xrightarrow{\circ} \tau_2$ (for example, a function with possible side effects)?

The specific counterexample given in the text is $\alpha = (\top \xrightarrow{\circ} \bot) \xrightarrow{\circ} \bot$. But I don't understand why it's so obvious that this is a counterexample.

Also, I don't understand how to check whether $\alpha = \bot \xrightarrow{\circ} \top$ is a (simpler) counterexample.